# write dynamic frame on s3 with xml format

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue, dynamic-frameworks

[caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GieSB.png)I want to write my dynamicframe on s3 with xml format . I want to get one xml file of my df. 
I TRIED THESES lines but got different parts of xml files . 
Who can help me to fix this problem please???

```
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = df, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://datalaketest1/temp"}, format = "xml", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to repartition to 1, so it will create only 1 output file:

```
repartitioned_df = df.repartition(1)
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = repartitioned_df, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://datalaketest1/temp"}, format = "xml", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
```

Comment: got error  **An error occurred while calling o109.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Traceback (most recent call last):**

Comment: 1- Are you sure that the line you shared was working and producing multiple files?
2- Can you verify that the frame name in the second line is correct?
3- Can you share the full error stack?

Comment: yep it created different files before.

Comment: Thank you . I added a caption in my original post

Comment: have you tried coalesce(1) instead of repartition(1) ?